# Typo in site description

Tags: bug, status-completed

From my Stack Exchange network profile, in the list of my accounts, this site has the following description:

[image]

It's missing the word "in". The site description on the Area 51 page is just fine.

Comment: Nice bug you got there

Comment: I mean nice bug got there

Comment: Blame Flimzy for that: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/22487/125254

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My bad. I accidentally a word there.

Comment: He he! That's a funny answer...

Comment: It's still missing... Does it take time to update?

Comment: @Gwenn All those displays are pretty heavily cached. The description has been updated, but it'll take a while to propagate around.